# "The service encountered an error." POST WCF REST service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, post

Made a post WCF service in C#, published. It was working before, but when I checked it on the other day, it gives me the error.

Here is the snipped code followed by the error.. can any one tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

```
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Vending : IVNService, IUSAService
{

    //first method sent by VendNovation. Checks if the given student is allow to make vending purchases
    //will be rejected if: student not found in system or student is marked inactive
    public AuthenticateCustomerResult AuthenticateCustomer(AuthenticateCustomerRequest request)
.... .... .... ....
```

Here is

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.NotSupportedException: A single WSDL document could not be generated for this service. Multiple service contract namespaces were found (http://vendnovation.com/, http://pos.usatech.com/). Ensure that all your service contracts have the same namespace.
at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlHelper.VerifyContractNamespace(List`1 wsdls)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlHelper.GetSingleWsdl(MetadataSet metadataSet)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureSingleWsdlInitialized()
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleMetadataRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Was told to keep namespaces same (vendnovation.com and pos.ustech.com), my question is why do we need to keep those two the same?

Here is from my code IVNService.cs

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://vendnovation.com/")]
//[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://vendnovation.com/"), XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IVNService
{
.....  ......    .....
```

and here is from another code IUSAService.cs

```
//[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://pos.usatech.com/"),     XmlSerializerFormat]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://pos.usatech.com/")]
interface IUSAService
{
```

Why do I need to keep them the same namespace?

Comment: From the error posted in the question: **Multiple service contract namespaces were found (http://vendnovation.com/, http://pos.usatech.com/). Ensure that all your service contracts have the same namespace**   Did you do this?

Comment: why do we need to keep them different? We have two clients. isn't it possible to keep both services functions in the same project?